# Can i make my app talk to Simtool Kit to determine the current tariff plan and balance in the SIM?

Tags: android, sim-toolkit

I am basically trying to develop an android app that can notify the user of the current call rate.

Can this be achieved using STK (Sim Tool Kit) ?

If i can get a sample code i can refer to, for giving basic instructions to the STK, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

Balances are not stored in the SIM. The SIM stores what is called the IMSI (International Mobile Subscriber Identity). When you authenticate with the network the IMSI is what is used to identify the subscriber by the operator.

Your Tariff plans are linked to your IMSI within the operators billing systems.